# Корректно ли сочетание?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Исключен из списков личного состава вуза (за смертью)" - правильно ли писать так: "за смертью"?

Answer (score 1):

Как раз в документах этот канцеляризм присутствует достаточно часто. 
ВУЗ, судя по всему, военный (ибо "личный состав"), поэтому спорить не стоит.
Во всех же остальных случаях рекомендуемый оборот - "отчислить в связи со смертью".

Comment: А мне он казался разговорным.

Comment: какой их двух?

Answer (score 0):

Одно из значений предлога ЗА - по причине: за ненадобностью,за отсутствием. Стилистических ограничений в словаре нет. Но, возможно, в документах делового стиля производный предлог **по причине** будет более уместен.